# Unreachable Code Error In Java

Tags: java, arraylist, unreachable-code

I'm working on a gradebook program in Java and I ran into a problem with "unreachable code" If somebody could tell me what is causing this issue I'd appreciate it.

```
     static ArrayList<String> assignments = new ArrayList<String>();
     static ArrayList<String> grades = new ArrayList<String>();

     public static String getAssignment(int a){
         return assignments.get(a);
         return grades.get(a);
     }
```

It's giving me the error "unreachable code" on return grades.get(a);

Comment: there can't be two return statement sequentially.

Comment: `return` ends the function and gives the value you return. You can't have 2 because you can only return 1 _value_. You can return arrays and, in some languages, tuples

Comment: you are returning two objects so second is unreachable

Comment: How exactly do you expect to return from a method *twice*?

Comment: Didn't know you could only return once

Answer (score 6):

You have two return statement, so the second one will never be reached.

Perhaps you intended to add a condition that would determine which of the two return statements should be executed.

Based on your method's name, it should return an assignment, not a grade :

```
 public static String getAssignment(int a){
     return assignments.get(a);
 }
```

But that depends on your logic.

Comment: I cant execute 2 return statements at once? They're parallel array lists so what can I do to make it work?

Comment: @GeorgeGuffey A method can only return one value. What do you expect your method to return?

Comment: @GeorgeGuffey: Define "make it work".  What are you actually trying to *do*?  The first `return` statement is "getting an assignment".  Which, based on the name of the method, sounds like reasonable behavior.  Why is the second `return` statement there?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Didn't know you could only return 1 thing in a method at once